# Text Classification using TfIdf and Bernoulli NB

Tags: classification, text-mining, naive-bayes, bernoulli-distribution

So, as I am reading about Bernoulli distribution and text classification, I want to understand how Bernoulli uses TfIdf features? Since TfIdf values are within [0-1) but Multivariate Bernoulli assumes that the features are 0/1. So, how does it work?

I also found this tutorial page on [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html) for text classification in which the train and test features are extracted as below:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,
                             stop_words='english')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_train.data)

X_test = vectorizer.transform(data_test.data)
```

and then Bernoulli distribution is applied:

```
clf = BernoulliNB(alpha=.01)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually, the features in the Bernoulli are indeed binary. However, you can control the threshold of when a certain Tfidf will be converted to a 0 or 1.

If you use scikit-learn, the parameter for [BernoulliNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html) is called

```
binarize : float or None, optional
Threshold for binarizing (mapping to booleans) of sample features. If None, input is presumed to already consist of binary vectors.
```

The more typical case for Bernoulli models is to set `binary=True` in the `CountVectorizer`. If you are using Tfidfs, you will probably have more success with a Multinomial model -- at least that is what I typically observe: Training naive Bayes models is cheap so I usually always compare both Bernoulli and Multinomial.